# Old publisher file will open with moved objects

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-publisher

I have an old publisher file, when I open it with the latest publisher version (2023) some images and objects are moved to a different location!

But when I open it with the 2007 version everything is fine about the images and objects.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: If you don't mind the document being hard (or impossible) to edit, export from the old version of Publisher as PDF or XPS: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-as-or-convert-a-publication-to-pdf-or-xps-using-publisher-657332d0-d2c2-464a-9870-e9b3d22e6469 or as a MS Word document: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/save-a-publication-as-a-word-document-b5eaaae5-6f1b-48c1-bebc-44460376b693 or open with LibreOffice, https://www.lifewire.com/open-pub-files-without-microsoft-publisher-1074669

Comment: @DrMoishePippik the problem is that 2023 will show the pages in color mode, but older versions will show pages in black and white :(

Comment: @DrMoishePippik in File -> Info the color is RGB, but in editing and viewing and exporting it is black and white with 2010 version. the 2023 will move objects to different locations :(

Comment: Exporting to PDF from v. 2010 does so only in B&W? Check options: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/convert-color-publisher-file-to-blackwhite/f078bf21-6b65-4751-b0b3-2f2369ca91ad

Comment: @DrMoishePippik it seems all images are set into grayscale in 2007 version (which is correct, I can right-click on images and select Format Picture and then in Image Control I will set color to automatic) but 2023 version will automatically convert all of them into automatic which cause moving objects and I do not know why!!! is there any to do a batch action on all images in 2007 version? for example making all images color into automatic instead of doing this one by one.